# how to write our required plugins

Tags: plugins, orientdb, geoserver

Hi I have a open source  PostGIS they provided plugins to connect Geo server .
like I have Orient db that doesn't supported By geo server so I want write plugins how can write is there any way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) [datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) for your database. There is a [tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html) that shows you how to create a new datastore. Once created you drop the jar into the GeoServer WEB-INF/lib folder and restart GeoServer which will use the SPI mechanism to pick up the new store.